# Jackson custom List instance type

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a need to map standard Json array to a custom List type (infact not java.util.List at all but javaslang.collection.List). Adding to the complexity, we don't have static beans where we could define the list type as javaslang type but we need to map to generic Map but the list instance should be of type javaslang.collection.List.

I tried with creating new custom deserializer but since we are trying to deser into generic Map, it is not touching that custom deserializer at all.

For ex., here is the test case we are looking to pass.

```
@Test
@DisplayName("list instance is javaslang list")
void listAsJsList() throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> object = objectMapper.readValue(
            "{\"records\": [{\"id\": \"123\"}, {\"id\": \"124\"} ] }", HashMap.class);
    assertThat(object.get("records")).isInstanceOf(javaslang.collection.List.class);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a deserializer for Map can get the desired results. Something like this:

```
class MapDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Map<String, Object>> {

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> deserialize(JsonParser paramJsonParser, DeserializationContext paramDeserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = paramJsonParser.getCodec().readTree(paramJsonParser);
        return parseObject(node);
     }

    private Map<String, Object> parseObject(JsonNode node) {
        Map<String, Object> object = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> itr = node.fields();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> entry = itr.next();
            if (entry.getValue().isArray())
                object.put(entry.getKey(), parseArray(entry.getValue()));
            else if (entry.getValue().isObject())
                object.put(entry.getKey(), parseObject(entry.getValue()));
            else
                object.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().asText());
        }
        return object;
    }

    private List<Object> parseArray(JsonNode node) {
        List<Object> list = List.of();
        Iterator<JsonNode> itr = node.elements();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            JsonNode currentNode = itr.next();
            if (currentNode.isObject())
                list = list.prepend(parseObject(currentNode));
            else if (currentNode.isArray())
                list = list.prepend(parseArray(currentNode));
            else
                list = list.prepend(currentNode.asText());
        }
        return list;
     }
}
```

Note:

- Above code will parse internal objects also to instance of type hashmaps, implementation can be changed as required.
- More cases can be added to handle string, integer etc. as instance of there respective types and exception handling can be done wherever required.

Sample usage of above deserializer:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addDeserializer(Map.class, new MapDeserializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);
Map<String, Object> result = mapper.readValue("{\"records\": [{\"id\": \"123\"}, {\"id\": \"124\"} ] }", Map.class);
if (result.get("records") instanceof javaslang.collection.List) {
    System.out.println("records are of type javaslang list");
}
// Prints: records are of type javaslang list
```